# SLAM using ydlidar g4

Tags: ros2, slam, mapping, lidar, ros-foxy

I am using a ydlidar g4 on ros2 foxy (Ubuntu 20.04). I succeeded at getting the view of the LiDAR on rviz2 following this tutorial: https://github.com/YDLIDAR/ydlidar_ros2_driver. But I want to generate a map of my room with it. I looked up on the net did not find a tutorial to do this. Do you have any idea of how to do SLAM using this LiDAR ?

If you have any suggestions on ros1 also I would like to hear them.

UPDATE: this is the file that I am trying to modify in order to generate the map. I still don't succeed at doing so, I don't know what's wrong with it !
Here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import LifecycleNode
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import LogInfo

import lifecycle_msgs.msg
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    share_dir = get_package_share_directory('ydlidar_ros2_driver')
    rviz_config_file = os.path.join(share_dir, 'config', 'ydlidar.rviz')
    parameter_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
    node_name = 'ydlidar_ros2_driver_node'

    params_declare = DeclareLaunchArgument('params_file',
                                           default_value=os.path.join(
                                               share_dir, 'params', 'ydlidar.yaml'),
                                           description='FPath to the ROS2 parameters file to use.')

    driver_node = LifecycleNode(package='ydlidar_ros2_driver',
                                node_executable='ydlidar_ros2_driver_node',
                                node_name='ydlidar_ros2_driver_node',
                                output='screen',
                                emulate_tty=True,
                                parameters=[parameter_file],
                                node_namespace='/',
                                )

    tf2_node = Node(package='tf2_ros',
                    node_executable='static_transform_publisher',
                    node_name='static_tf_pub_laser',
                    arguments=['0', '0', '0.02', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'base_link', 'laser_frame'],
                    )

    slam_toolbox_node = Node(package='slam_toolbox',
                             node_executable='async_slam_toolbox_node',
                             output='screen',
                             parameters=[parameter_file],
                             remappings=[('/scan', '/LaserScan')],
                             )

    rviz2_node = Node(package='rviz2',
                      node_executable='rviz2',
                      node_name='rviz2',
                      arguments=['-d', rviz_config_file],
                      )

    return LaunchDescription([
        params_declare,
        driver_node,
        slam_toolbox_node,
        tf2_node,
        rviz2_node,
    ])
```

I get the following on rviz: [image: RVIZ visualization warning]

Some warnings on map and TF !